# How to parallelize loops with an include in ansible

Tags: asynchronous, ansible

Recently I came across a bottleneck in our ansible playbooks' code. We were deploying our clusters (e.g. a [mongoDB Replica Set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/)) sequentially - i.e. one VM after another, each waiting for the previous to be up and running.

This slowed down the whole cluster deploy time by a factor of the members on it.

To solve this, I started digging on [ansible's async actions and pooling](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/playbooks_async.html) and found out a few examples on parallel loops and "*fire-and-forget*" strategies for scenarios like ours.

The particular thing is, we have defined our own "customize the VM and spawn it" ansible task (`create_instance.yml`) that gets included and receives the different customization variables from the playbook and abstracts the whole process by running different KVM/shell commands.

Using ["*Parallel task execution in Ansible*"](http://toroid.org/ansible-parallel-dispatch) as reference, I ended up having something like:

```
- name: Generate VMs for DB
  hosts: hypervisor_fe
  tags: platform,mongodb
  tasks:
    - include: tasks/create_instance.yml
      vars:
        vm: "{{ item }}"
      with_items: "{{ mongodb.vms }}"
      register: mongo_instances
      async: 7200
      poll: 0

    - name: Wait for instance creation to complete
      async_status: jid={{ item.ansible_job_id }}
      register: mongo_jobs
      until: mongo_jobs.finished
      retries: 300
      with_items: "{{ mongo_instances.results }}"
```

However, **this setup does seem to ignore all the new async code and keeps the old, sequential behavior.** I'm guessing this has to do with the no. and granularity of plays inside the imported task. If I instead replace the `include` for a **single, explicit** long-running task - let's say, e.g.

```
- name: Test async operation
  shell: ping -c1 {{ item.hostname }} && sleep 20
```

This does seem to work just fine, running one ping to each `item` and then moving on to the next action.

Is this assumption right? Does someone has experience with `include` and async loops in ansible? Do I need to move the async declaration to a single play inside the imported code?

Comment: Based on what I read in https://stackoverflow.com/a/39207589/2172072 by @konstantin-suvorov: "include can't use async keyword" - thus, this seems not to be an option right now. Digging on ansible's GH found out this FR: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/22716

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I advise you to rethink your playbook design in the following way:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - add_host:
        name: "{{ item.name }}"
        groups: new_vms
        vm: "{{ item }}"
      with_items: "{{ mongodb.vms }}"

- hosts: new_vms
  tasks:
    - include: create_instance.yml
```

And inside `create_instance.yml` use `delegate_to: hypervisor_fe`.

This gives you native Ansible host loop for every vm with concurrent execution of each task.

Comment: Won't this fail with "unreachable" when trying to gather the facts of  `new_vms` (not yet created)? Is there a way to apply the `delegate_to` to all tasks on the include? (~30)

Comment: You can disable it with `gather_facts: no` and collect them later with `setup` module. You can apply `delegate_to: localhost` to `include` statement or add `block` into your task file and apply `delegate_to` to the block.